# How to persistently set NGINX variable in Lua

Tags: nginx, lua, devops, nginx-config

I wanted to change the value of the variable `$subdomain` using a lua script. This subdomain is mapped to a port number in a `lua_shared_dict` thus when a request is sent, for example `http://subdomain.domain.com/test` will `proxy_pass` to `http://domain:8080/` where the subdomain is mapped to 8080 prior to the request. Here's the code:

```
location = /test {
    if ($host ~* "^([^.]+)" ) {
        set $proxy_port $1;
    }

    rewrite_by_lua_block {
        local sd_map = ngx.shared.sd_map # where subdomain is mapped to 8080
        local subdomain = ngx.var.proxy_port # the initial value of subdomain

        if (uuid:get(subdomain) ~= nil) then
            ngx.var.proxy_port = uuid:get(subdomain) # assigned value to $proxy_port
        else
            ngx.status = ngx.HTTP_NOT_FOUND
            ngx.exit(404)
        end
    }

    echo $proxy_port; 
    set $proxy_url "http://domain:$proxy_port"; 
    echo $proxy_url; # The Variable proxy_port in here returns the subdomain and not the mapped port 
}
```

The output from the first `echo $proxy_port` returns the right value, however, the second `$proxy_port` variable inside `echo $proxy_url` returns the subdomain. My guess is that the set function, sets the `$proxy_url` variable before `rewrite_by_lua_block` is called, thus why calling echo results in two different outputs from the same variable.

I tried using

```
set_by_lua_block $proxy_port { 
    # Same code as above but with return value
    return mapped_port 
}
```

Which works and outputs the correct `$proxy_port and $proxy_url` variables but I wanted to retain the use of

```
ngx.status = ngx.HTTP_NOT_FOUND
ngx.exit(404)
```

which `set_by_lua_block` seems to be incapable of executing, because it would throw an error in exit. I don't want to go the hard-coded route of defining the 404 path in the else statement.